# Displaying the UK on a Google map

Tags: android

I have created an application in which I have displayed a Google map (version 3.0 tablet).

I need to show **the UK**, with zoom, when I load it for the first time.

The user should be able to zoom in and zoom out.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
private MapController mapController;
mapController = mapView.getController();
mapController.setCenter(new GeoPoint((int)(54*1E6),(int)(-2*1E6))); // UK coords
mapController.setZoom(4);
mapView.postInvalidate();
```

Comment: your concept is right but it not get me uk map i think geopint is wrong

Comment: yes i have commented that use the geopoints for UK i.e : Latitude: 54
Longitude: -2